# Excel VBA - Sheet data Comparison

Tags: excel, vba

I am comparing data in two sheets. In this code only else part is getting executed and if I use r1.value, it throws type mismatch error.
Please suggest improvements.
here is my code:

```
Sub compareData()
Dim r As Range
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set r1 = Intersect(.Range("A:A"), .UsedRange)
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Set r2 = Intersect(.Range("A:A"), .UsedRange)
    End With

    For Each r In r2
        If r1.Text <> r2.Text Then
            r.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Closed"
            Else
            r.Offset(0, 4).Value = 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`r1` is a range of many cells, so its value is an array. `r` is a single cell so its value is single variant. You can't compare an array to a single variant hence the type mismatch.

If you are trying to check for each text in `r2` if it is present in r1, this test can achieve it:

```
For Each r In r2
    If Application.CountIf(r1, r.Text) = 0 Then
        r.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Closed"
    Else
        r.Offset(0, 4).Value = 1
    End If
Next r
```

---

If you want to compare the two columns for equality on the same positions, you can do it with a loop like this:

```
Dim i as Long
For i = 1 to r2.rows.Count
   If r2.Cells(i, 1).Value2 = r1.Cells(i, 1).Value2 Then
        r2.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Closed"
    Else
        r2.Cells(i, 4).Value = 1
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you very much...! code is working absolutely fine. Still, I am  looking for other ways to compare array values. Is there any other way to compare such 'Range' values?

Comment: @user3130361 See the added section in answer.